# Working around "Windows NT 6.0 or above required"

Tags: linux, wine

Im trying to run an installer file on Linux with Wine, specifically installing JetBrains dotPeek.  The installer fails instantly with:

```
JetBrains dotPeek currently requires Windows NT 6.0 of higher to run.
Your operating system version is not suported
```

My question is, how do I run this file, and install dotPeek?
Is there a way to update wines NT version?  Or some workaround to running the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, this should already be the default in current Wine versions – "NT 6" is the series starting with Vista (NT 6.0) and Windows 7 (NT 6.1).

If you have an older Wine prefix, run `winecfg` and in the "Applications" tab select a more recent Windows version to emulate (e.g. Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 would be a good option).